# How to show facebook comments "Add comment" field by default

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-comments

I'm using facebook commenting plugin for my website and I came across one small problem.
When a certain number of comments are made, the "Add comment" field disappears and user has to click on add comment link to show it.

This one:

[image]

---

I want to know if there is a way to always show "Add comment" field no matter how many comments are there.

So it looks like this:

[image]

**EDIT:** Here is my facebook-comments code

---

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=/*my app ID*/";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://myweb.com/<?php echo "$article_id";?>" data-num-posts="10" data-width="520"></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to 'Edit Comment Settings' and check 'Always show' in the Comments composer section. You need to be logged in as administrator for that page in order to configure comments settings.

[image: Edit Comments Settings screenshot]

Comment: I am logged in as an admin and I have specidied my admin id in meta tags, but I don't see anything like "Eddit comment settings", I do have links like Public comments/moderation view/Settings, but none of them contains anything similar to what you posted.

Comment: Oh in settings it asks for fb_app:id to see global settings. Is it necessary? do you use one?

Comment: Yes it turned out that I needed app_id to go in there )) Thank you for the answer, I'll reward a bounty once stackowerflow allows me (after 2h)

Comment: I am sorry I don't really understand this I have the same problem, not sure how I fix it I am getting the code for the comments box embed from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ does that mean I need to find the settings there on on my facebook page?

Answer (score 1):

I tried it at my end and by default the comment box was shown. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Did you try overriding CSS?

```
#facebook .hidden_elem {
display: none !important;
}
```

In your css mention it as :

```
   #facebook .hidden_elem {
    display: block !important;
    }
```

Comment: no this didn't work and I din't overwrite the css. Thnx for try )))

Comment: Just changing style wouldn't work anyway, as there is quite something happening when you click on add comment link. See onclick event in inspector for details.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be the admin of this page,

go to :

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments

--> Settings->Comments Composer-> Always Show