# Keep Facebook commentbox open

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-comments

*Hello*,

I would like to know how to keep the Facebook commentbox opened by default instead of clicking on "Leave a comment" first, so that people can write directly in there.

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: Have a look look at this [Question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616178/how-to-show-facebook-comments-add-comment-field-by-default

Answer (score 2):

You have to be the admin of this page,

go to :

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments

--> Settings->Comments Composer-> Always Show